# Deliver_later not working for legacy site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've got a legacy site I'm working on that is giving me a new error. It's Rails 5.1.0.rc2.

Site uses the below similar coding in other mailer actions, which are giving this error:

```
Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 03897c07-3397-4b37-8c62-cfcf12dd1905) from Async(mailers) in 244.32ms: NoMethodError (undefined method `deliver_later' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fe7e5c9d9c8>
Did you mean?  delivery_handler):
/home/dave/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail/message.rb:1396:in `method_missing'
```

controller:

```
UserMailer.hpe_new_vehicle_applicant(@dealer,@vehicle,@user).deliver_later
```

user_mailer:

```
def hpe_new_vehicle_applicant(dealer,vehicle,user)
    @dealer = dealer
    @vehicle = vehicle
    @user = user

    account_emails = @dealer.sales_persons.where.not(confirmed_at: nil).pluck(:email)
    subject = "no reply - New Vehicle Applicant (#{@dealer.dealer_name})"

    account_emails.each do |email|
      send_user_mail(email, subject).deliver_later
    end

  end
```

I'm thinking the code worked previously, but I'm not sure. Also no changes have been done except to update bcrypt gem. ... I'm also not seeing why send_user_mail is being used. No real results show when googled.

Update: 'send_user_mail(email, subject)' was a call to a function within user_mailer that sent the email, which at some point acquired .deliver_later that broke it.

Comment: You are calling deliver_later twice. This code likely never worked